# Hidden Notification in StartForeground in xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, background-service

Can I Hidden notification "App Name Is Running" When Service Runs in the background?

My Notification Is:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
   .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.navigation_empty_icon)
   .SetVibrate(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 })
   .SetSound(null)
   .SetChannelId(channelId)
   .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityMin)
   .SetAutoCancel(true)
   .SetContentTitle("")
   .SetContentText("")
   .SetNotificationSilent()
   .SetOngoing(false);
 
StartForeground(1, builder.Build());
```

Comment: What does the hidden notification mean? If  you want the notification do not pop up, you could change the priority when below API level 26. Starting with API level 26 or above, you need to set channel priority.

Comment: this mean How to run StartForeground without Notification?

Answer (score 0):

> this mean How to run StartForeground without Notification?

We could not run StartForeground without Notification. The notification is mandatory.

StartForeground takes two parameters, both of which are mandatory:

- An integer value that is unique within the application to identify
  the service.
- A Notification object that Android will display in the
  status bar for    as long as the service is running.

For more details, please check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: so how to run program in background without notification????

Comment: We always use the service to do the background work. How do you do the baclground work? And what is the notification look like in your background?

Comment: when my service has run show notification "App name is running" . i want dont show this.  is there any way else to run app in background without service??